# Campos novos devise ficam nil, o que fazer?

Tags: ruby, devise, jwt

Pessoal estou implantando token e autenticação,estou utilizando JWT e Devise, estou tendo um problema com Devise, eu não quero utilizar o email para autenticação, eu quero usar uma matricula, então li a documentação do Devise e fiz os seguintes ajustes, porem o erro ainda persiste, ele não reconhece o parâmetro de matricula na hora de adicionar usuários.

```
Model User

class User < ApplicationRecord

attr_accessor :registration

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end

Controler Application

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  attr_reader :current_user

private
  before_filter :configure_devise_params, if: :devise_controller?
  def configure_devise_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:registration, :email, :password,  :password_confirmation)
    end

  end

  protected
  def authenticate_request!
    unless user_id_in_token?
      render json: { errors: ['Not Authenticated'] }, status: :unauthorized
      return
    end
    @current_user = User.find(auth_token[:user_id])
  rescue JWT::VerificationError, JWT::DecodeError
    render json: { errors: ['Not Authenticated'] }, status: :unauthorized
  end

  private
  def http_token
      @http_token ||= if request.headers['Authorization'].present?
        request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ').last
      end
  end

  def auth_token
    @auth_token ||= JsonWebToken.decode(http_token)
  end

  def user_id_in_token?
    http_token && auth_token && auth_token[:user_id].to_i
  end
end
```

No meu banco eu já criei os campos de `registration`, `email`, `password` e `password_confirmation`.

Porém quando tento criar um usuário, por mais que eu passe os dados, ele instância com nulo.

```
u = User.new(email:'a@a.com', registration:192536, password:'changeme', password_confirmation:'changeme')

=> #<User id: nil, email: "a@a.com", registration: nil>
```

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: consegui resolver pessoa.... adicionando as linhas no application controler

before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

#metodo que adiciona campos ao devise strong_paramsn, auth com email ou matricula
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:registration, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :sign_up, keys: added_attrs
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: added_attrs
  end

Comment: tentou remover o ", :validatable"

Answer (score 1):

Em seu controller você deve utilizar um before_action para executar o método que irá configurar os parâmetros permitidos pelo devise na criação da conta. Por exemplo, pará configurar os parâmetros permitidos na criação e na alteração da conta, veja o código abaixo:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user_params|
      user_params.permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end
  end

end
```